# how to start a new instance of terminal in current terminal window ? (in Redhat)

Tags: command-line

I'm working on a project to port a windows program to Linux.

Is there any command I'm using Redhat to replace the equivilent of the windows **cmd /c**? (btw, **gnome-terminal -x** doesn't work for me)

**cmd** means start a new instance of command interpreter(without creating a new cmd window).

**/c** means Carries out the command specified by String and then stops.

Comment: Is `bash -c` what you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe @Seth has the correct idea, but why do you want to start a another command interpreter, like `bash` why not run a script ? You may be suffering from a windows paradigm that doesn't apply in Linux, could you elaborate what you are trying to achieve please.